# How to return an ArrayList with Billions of record from Kafka Producer?

Tags: java, apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api, apache-kafka-connect

I have prepared a kafka producer which puts an List into the kafka topic. It works fine for 1 Million of lines/records. The production file I have got, consists of 110Million+ records. 
**What is the best way to deal with such huge data at my KafkaProducer?**

Below is the code, I have used to process 1 Million records and it takes around 4 minutes to put the same into kafka topic.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Schema;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.SchemaBuilder;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.data.Struct;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.connect.source.SourceTask;

public class KafkaSourceTask extends SourceTask {

    private String filename;

    private String topic;

    private RandomAccessFile raf;

    private long lastRecordedOffset = 0L;

    private BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;

    Schema schema = SchemaBuilder.struct().field("emp_id", 
            Schema.STRING_SCHEMA).field("name", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA)
            .field("last_name", Schema.STRING_SCHEMA).field("department", 
            Schema.STRING_SCHEMA).build();

public void start(Map<String, String> props) {
    filename = props.get("file");
    topic = props.get("topic");

}

@Override
public List<SourceRecord> poll() throws InterruptedException {
    double startTime = System.nanoTime();
    try {
        bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(new File(filename)),
                StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        raf = new RandomAccessFile(filename, "r");
        long filePointer = raf.getFilePointer();
        System.out.println(filePointer + " - " + lastRecordedOffset);
        if (bufferedReader.ready() && (filePointer > lastRecordedOffset || filePointer == 0)) {
            raf.seek(lastRecordedOffset);

            ArrayList<SourceRecord> records = new ArrayList<>();
            String line;
            while ((line = raf.readLine()) != null) {
                records.add(new SourceRecord(null, null, topic, schema, buildRecordValue(line)));
            }
            lastRecordedOffset = raf.getFilePointer();
            raf.close();
            bufferedReader.close();

            double endTime = System.nanoTime();
            return records;
        }
    }
    catch (IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
public synchronized void stop() {
    try {
        raf.close();
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private Struct buildRecordValue(String line) {
    String[] values = line.split(",");
    Struct value = new Struct(schema).put("emp_id", values[0]).put("name", values[1]).put("last_name", values[2])
            .put("department", values[3]);
    return value;
}

@Override
public String version() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}
}
```

Any help or suggestion on this will be appreciated.Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why do you create an actual `List` first? You can just send each record as you create them.

Comment: Will it not create extra overhead? I am having one billion of record so 1 billion requests will be sent to the Kafka Server. I have not tried that, but assuming it will take more time and the overhead will be more. Please rectify me, if my assumption is wrong.

Comment: If you are trying to read a CSV, why not use this existing Connector? https://github.com/jcustenborder/kafka-connect-spooldir

Comment: from where are you getting data? why don't you have multiple producers ?

Comment: @Deadpool Maybe line order matters?

Comment: if he needs order also, there is no guarantee of order in kafka right? i mean it may go to different partitions @cricket_007

Comment: @Deadpool The number of partitions wasn't mentioned. I can only guess... Or OP is just not aware of multi-threaded file reading.

Comment: @Deadpool I am getting this file from mainframe system. Its a huge file dumped everyday containing 250+million records. I need to read it every day and put the same into KAFKA topic. I am able to read(using java 8 stream API) the file within 5 minutes. But when I am trying to put it into an ArrayList it is taking a lot of time. I know creating arrayList with such huge data is causing the issue. But I am not sure about the better way to put such huge data into kafka if not using SourceTask Kindly help me on this. Any help, example or code snipped will help a lot.

Comment: Honestly, just send them one by one. Kafka is far more suited for smallish messages; in fact, I'd imagine it might not be able to handle the whole thing at once. The "overhead" should be negligible.

Comment: What is that file format @bibhu_bioit

Comment: And you don't need to save in arraylist, there are couple of ways to do it, if you can try breaking file into small files 4 or 5 and read parallely @bibhu_bioit

Comment: @Deadpool It's a CSV file. By saying "breaking into small files", do you mean myFile.CSV will be splitted and myFile_part1.csv, myFile_part2.csv....myFile_part100.csv. or I have to read some lines of the original file and consider it a small file? A bit of explanation will be helpful.

Comment: on my research i believe this approach will not give you any benefits, need couple of answers here 1) are you reading line by line? or 2)parsing whole csv into list? 3) and i will suggest you to try this approach read csv file using `openCSV` each row and as soon as you read it send it to kafka, don't save it in memory like `adding to list` @bibhu_bioit

Comment: @Deadpool I will be trying that and let you know the results for that. I was wondering if 250million hits to kafka server will create more overhead in case I am sending one record at a time.

Comment: Kafka producer is thread safe, it will take care of it, that should work

Answer (score 0):

*An ArrayList with billions of records*?  Think about it, if you have even 1 billion, and the size of each record is only 1 byte (a ridiculous underestimate), you have 1 SI gigabyte of memory consumption.

By the rough and ready definition of "Big Data", as data that will not fit into memory on a single host, you are either at the edge of or past that point, and you need to start using big data techniques.  First you can try multithreading this, and next you can try multithreading on multiple machines, that's the advantage of using Kafka-- the client API-- both when consuming from or producing to, makes this easy.

Answer (score 0):

To begin with, Kafka producer batch records before sending them to the brokers, you should check and play with the two configs `linger.ms`
 and `batch.record.size`.

Now you can use an other thread to read the file (I think it's one record per line) and put them in a  java queue, and use the thread hosting kafka producer to read this queue continuously.

Multiple producers is considered an anti pattern especially when writing to a Kafka topic, check the Single Writer Principle.

Well either way you will have to tweak a little bit your kafka producer but like @cricket_007 said it you should consider to use kafka connect with a file csv connector, at least if you don't find a connector that suits you, you can develop a connector yourself.

Hope that's help.